# Intent java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Добрый день,

наткнулся на проблему с перезапуском activity.
При запуске функции restartTheGame непосредственно по нажатию кнопки проблем никаких не возникает, все работает.

Но если я вызываю  данный метод из AlertDialog, то приложение крашится.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.fgurbanov.skynet.myminesweeper, PID: 4506
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:133)
                  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
                  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4449)
                  at com.fgurbanov.skynet.myminesweeper.GameActivity.restartGame(GameActivity.java:98)
                  at com.fgurbanov.skynet.myminesweeper.GameActivity$2.onClick(GameActivity.java:172)
                  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Буду рад любой подсказке для решения проблемы.

```
    <Button
        android:text="Restart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Restart_button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="restartTheGame"/>
```

сам код Activity

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static TextView scoreTextView;
private static TextView flagTextView;

public String[] ScoreList;

static SharedPreferences sPref;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


    //определим счетчики
    scoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    flagTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mine_left);

    //загрузим данные прошлых игр
    loadScoreList();
    //Log.e("something Load", ScoreList[0]);
    //запустим игру
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int size = intent.getIntExtra("size", 0);
    Log.e("size"," "+size);
    if (size > 2){
        int[][] genGrid = new int[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            genGrid[i]  = intent.getIntArrayExtra("step_"+i);
        }
        GameEngine.getInstance().createGrid(this,genGrid);
    } else {
        GameEngine.getInstance().createGrid(this);
    }

}


public static TextView getScoreTextView() {
    return scoreTextView;
}


public static TextView getFlagTextView() {
    return flagTextView;
}


private static GameActivity instance;
public static  GameActivity getInstance() {
    if ( instance == null ){
        instance = new GameActivity();
    }
    return instance;
}


public void saveLastResult(){
    SaveScoreList();
}


public void restartTheGame(View view) {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    int[][] genGrid =  GameEngine.getInstance().GenerateGrid;
    intent.putExtra("size",genGrid[0].length);
    for (int i = 0; i < genGrid.length; i++  ){
        intent.putExtra("step_" + i,genGrid[i]);
    }
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
    this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}


public void startNewGame(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    GameEngine.getInstance().isGameEnd = false;
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

public void checkEndGame(final View view) {
    if (GameEngine.getInstance().isGameEnd){

        String title = "Game Over";
        if (GameEngine.getInstance().isGameFailed) {
            title += " YOU DIED";
        } else {
            title += "YOU WIN";
        }

        String message = "Your Score " + GameEngine.getInstance().getScore();


        Log.e("GameActivity.this", GameActivity.this.toString());
        Log.e("this", this.toString());
        Log.e("getInstance", getInstance().toString());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("End",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                        saveLastResult();
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Restart",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                        //restartGame();//////////////////////////
                        restartTheGame(view);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Start NewGame",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                        saveLastResult();
                        startNewGame();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
public void refreshLayer(View view) {
    int flag = GameEngine.getInstance().getFlag();
    flagTextView.setText(Integer.toString(flag));
    int score = GameEngine.getInstance().getScore();
    scoreTextView.setText(Integer.toString(score));
    checkEndGame(view);
}

public void  SaveScoreList() {
    sPref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putInt("Status_size", ScoreList.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < ScoreList.length; i++ ){
        ed.putString("Status_" + i, ScoreList[i]);
    }
    ed.apply();
    //ed.commit();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Score saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void loadScoreList()
{
    sPref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int size = sPref.getInt("Status_size", 0);
    if ( size < 2 ){
        ScoreList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_result);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ScoreList[i] = sPref.getString("Status_" + i, "");
        }
    }
}



}
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки покажите.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev прошу прощения, добавил

Answer (score 2):

Передайте контекст `Activity`, а не `View` в конструктор `AlertDialog.Builder()`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но тогда в данном случае он сразу вылетает, не создавая диалог.
Сделал как вы сказали, ошибка переместилась на  строчку c изменениеми в builder: 

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @norbertf в какой строчке кода на этот раз?

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Comment: @norbertf так что на момент вызова данного метода у вас активити ==null получается